# How to Check if an image is valid on iPhone

Tags: iphone, javax.imageio

**How to Check if an image is valid**

For example, when I cached an image which was downloaded only half and failed, and this image is invalid, then I want to know it's an invalid image and download again.
(When I use the broken image, Xcode console logs an error: 
**ImageIO:   PNG IDAT: CRC error** )

**So I want find a mechanism to check image's validation**
for different kinds of JPEG,PNG,etc

anybody has some clues?

Comment: here is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094956/how-can-i-validate-an-image-file-i-download-from-the-web-on-iphone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by checking for valid header.
Secondly the footer. Usually the last 8 bytes uint values in order are
'73,69,78,68,174,66,96,130'. 
This converted into a Int64 equals 5279712195050102914

This should do for a png :)

> if (memcmp(img_bytes, "\211PNG", 4) != 0||OSReadBigInt64(img_bytes,(length - 8))!=5279712195050102914)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   //Bad Data! Free your data and return or something
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Begeesy' answer should suffice. A more complete solution is to check the first 8 bytes rather than limit it to the first 4. "\211PNG\r\n\032\n". See the PNG Signature File section of http://www.fileformat.info/format/png/spec/4b57267b1c1941cf8794fdc952287a26/view.htm

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are using same class to download image file from server and you request consequent download of same file, while it is already downloading that file, which fails the earlier one file download and results in partly downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to get the file size of the image & compare with the image file just downloaded.

Comment: it's an easy way, but I want check the image itself.

Comment: do you mean you want to perform CRC in Objective-C. Somebody has tried before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974961/why-does-crc-return-different-value-when-inside-objective-c-method-instead-of-st

Answer (score 0):

For loading images from the network there are two obvious failure cases:

1. The downloaded file was not an image at all.
2. The downloaded data only contains part of the image data.

For the first case nil checking the return value of various UIImage methods is probably the best way to handle this error case.

The following class methods on `UIImage` will return nil if the image could not be initialized with the data it was provided: `+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data` and `+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`.

Code that does the nil check might look like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];
if (image) {
    // The image was loaded. Display it
}
else {
    // The image was not loaded. Redownload or display a placeholder, etc...
}
```

For the second failure case it is likely the result of lost connection. For this case the failure is best handled in the NSURLConnection's delegate.  When downloading the image if `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` is called then the data for the request should be discarded.

Also keep in mind that `didFailWithError:` will not be called for 4xx or 5xx responses from the server. It is called when the connection is cut off for other reasons. It would generally be a good idea to make sure you only write image data to disk when the server has responded with a 200 OK.

Comment: No,  if the header of image is well, then it can be initialized as an UIImage and then display half

Comment: I have updated the answer on how to deal with two common failure cases. Only checking the image itself is hard because you have to deal with all the different formats individually. Hard, annoying and generally not worth it.